# How to ship a large number of files in wix installer?

Tags: c#, wix, custom-action

I have a large number of files ( > 1000) and I want to ship all these files through my Wix installer. I have zipped the related files and shipped those zip files and extracted them through a custom action. Is there any other better solution for this case? Whether the zip and extraction is a proper way in my case?

Comment: Why don't you just install the files the standard way (File table)? `Heat.exe` will help you creating the neccessary wxs file. You solution might work for install, but you will have a hard time servicing your installation (repair, upgrade, uninstall).

Comment: File count will be increased for each release. So it is not possible to maintain all those files individually. So only, I zipped all the relevant files and shipped them. Individual files will be shipped separately.

Comment: This is exactly the scanario supported by automatic file harvesting using `Heat.exe`. See [here](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/overview/heat.html) for instructions.

Comment: If you are in a corporate setting, maybe check for a packaging team who takes care of packaging internal and third party applications. A dialog with them would save you a lot of grief I think. Your manager should know if there is such a team?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a fairly straight forward tutorial how to enable harvest in a WiX project:
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1107786/Enabling-Harvest-Heat-exe-in-a-Wix-Setup-Project

The harvest will be able to collect all artifacts from your application at build. Which means you never have to think about new files getting added.